# Rolling window on dataframe rows Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to create a rolling window (2 periods) over a dataframe rows and compute the sum of the values?

My data:

```
ID Name Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
0   A      2       2      4      4
1   B      1       1      3      3
```

The output desired:

```
ID Name Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4   Rol1 Rol2 Rol3
0   A      2       2      4      4       4    6    8
1   B      1       1      3      3       2    4    6
```

I tried to use df.rolling() but was only able to use it on a specific column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), but first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) of all columns which cannot be used in function and last add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove all `NaN`s columns:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['ID','Name'])
       .rolling(2, axis=1).sum()
       .dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
#rename columns
df1.columns = ['Roll{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(df1.columns)+1)]
print (df1)
         Roll1  Roll2  Roll3
ID Name                     
0  A       4.0    6.0    8.0
1  B       2.0    4.0    6.0
```

Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) output to original:

```
df = df.join(df1, on=['ID','Name'])
print (df)
   ID Name  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Roll1  Roll2  Roll3
0   0    A       2       2       4       4    4.0    6.0    8.0
1   1    B       1       1       3       3    2.0    4.0    6.0
```